# Basex Xquery filter retrieved data

Tags: basex

```
<a id="aId" deleted="false">
    <b id="bIdOne" deleted="false">
        <c>cValue</c>
        <d id="dId" deleted="true">
            <e>eValue</e>
        </d>
        <f id="fId" deleted="false">
            <g>gValue</g>
        </f>
    </b>
    <b id="bIdTwo" deleted="true">
        <c>cValue</c>
        <d id="dId" deleted="true">
            <e>eValue</e>
        </d>
        <f id="fId" deleted="false">
            <g>gValue</g>
        </f>
    </b>
    <b id="bIdThree" deleted="false">
        <c>cValue</c>
        <d id="dId" deleted="true">
            <e>eValue</e>
        </d>
        <f id="fId" deleted="true">
            <g>gValue</g>
        </f>
    </b>
    <Y><yValue</Y>
</a>
```

Expected Output :

retrieve list of b and its child where deleted attribute is false, Expected output is below

### query should be something like :
for $x in $data//*descendant::*[(@deleted=\"false\" or empty(@deleted))]  return $x/b";

```
<b id="bIdOne" deleted="false">
    <c>cValue</c>
        <f id="fId" deleted="false">
            <g>gValue</g>
        </f>
</b>
<b id="bIdThree" deleted="false">
    <c>cValue</c>
    <Y><yValue</Y>
</b>
```

Comment: There are `deleted` attributes in `<a>`, `<b>`,`<d>` and `<f>`. Does the attribute value have to be `false` in `<b>` only or also in the others?

Comment: Nothing about this is BaseX specific. You might get more attention if you tagged it as XQuery and XQuery3

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
let $data := [your code above, fixed - your <Y> is in the wrong place for your output]

return
element root 
  {    
   for $e1 in $data//b[@deleted="false"] 
   let $dat :=$e1//*[not(@deleted="true")][not(ancestor::*[@deleted="true"])]

   return
   element{name($e1)}{$e1/@*,$dat}      
  }
```

Output should be your desired output.